# How to connect to a repository on Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I've read through the documentation and I can't find a way to connect to a repository on Gitlab to download it or commit my project to it.

On Github there are links to the repository and you can use the desktop client to connect. On Gitlab I don't see anything like that.

Here's what I found from Gitlab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html

It talks about connecting via a terminal and SSH.

I've tried this and it fails to connect:

`ssh -T git@gitlab.com/groups/myprojects/myproject/`

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname
> gitlab.com/groups/myprojects/myproject/: nodename nor servname
> provided, or not known

I'd rather not use the command line if possible. I've looked at all the gitlab documentation and maybe it's there but I can't find it. I just want to clone a repository and commit to it.

**UPDATE:**
I've found this page, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/tutorials/make_your_first_git_commit.html, that steps through some of this. I'll keep this page updated if it covers this.

Comment: Why not just use `git clone https://gitlab.com/username/reponame` or clone it using the same URL in your GUI git client of choice?

Comment: @dan1st Can I use Github Desktop client to clone it?

Comment: Yes, just click the clone button (possibly a `+` or `Add repository` or similar) and paste in the URL.

Comment: I'm guessing your URL is not formatted correctly. It should be something like `git@host:path` and not `git@host/path`. The GitLab GUI should provide the URL for easy copy/pasting.

Comment: Github desktop worked for cloning the repository. I'll see if it works for committing changes

Comment: `I've tried this and it fails to connect:` that differs from the command in the linked docs (which doesn’t have a path - probably to avoid the invalid syntax in the question). `I'd rather not use the command line if possible` - fwiw it’s worth knowing minimally what a gui is doing for you to not be able to figure out what happens when things go wrong :).

Comment: regarding joanis' comment: use `ssh -T git@gitlab.com:groups/myprojects/myproject/`

Comment: @AD7six I'm using Github desktop and it's working same as with github. I did work on the command line a bit but it had been a while

Comment: No, don't even use the colon, it's just `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` or `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` for testing. You need the `groups/myprojects/...` part only when *cloning*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same GitHub Desktop for GitLab repositories, as long as:

- you use a [GitLab PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) as a password for HTTPS GitLab repository URL;
- a [registered SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account) for SSH GitLab repository URL.

An ssh command would not work with a repository SSH URL, but GitHub Desktop would know how to clone/pull/push said repository with that same URL.